# Uninitialized floating point variables, repoducing indeterminate behavior

Tags: c#, c++, .net, floating-point, undefined-behavior

I had to debug some code that was exhibiting transient and sporadic behavior, which ultimately could be attributed to an uninitialized float in a line of initializations, i.e.:

```
float a = number, b, c = other_number;
```

This section of code was rapidly sampling a device over a serial connection and averaging the output over some interval. Every once in a while, the number **2.7916085e+035** would get reported, but otherwise the code worked as intended and the bug was not reproducible.

Since the number was always **2.7916085e+035**, I thought there might have been some issues with the communications handling, or the device itself, but these were ruled out. I was almost ready to blame it on external interference until I finally caught a faulty sample in the debugger.

So, to the question. Can someone postulate the significance of **2.7916085e+035**? I'm not sure it has any meaning outside of my context, but what bothers me is that this number was essentially unreproducibly *reproducible*. That is to say, I couldn't replicate the problem reliably, but when it arose, it was always the same thing. From my understanding, uninitialized variables are supposed to be indeterminate. It's worth noting that the issue happened in all different places of program execution, phase, time of day, etc... but always on the same system.

Is there something in the .NET framework, runtime, or operating system that was causing the behavior? This was particularly troublesome to track down because the uninitialized variable always had the same value, when it didn't luckily get set to 0.

Edit: Some context. The code is within a timer with a variable tick rate, so the variables are local non-static members of a class:

```
if(//some box checked)
{
    switch(//some output index)
    {
        case problem_variable:
        {
            if(ready_to_sample)
            {
               float average;

               for each(float num in readings)
               {
                 average += num;
               }

               average /= readings.Count;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

The variable in question here would be `average`. `readings` is a list of outputs that I want to average. `average` would be redeclared one time per.... average, which can happen in seconds, minutes, hours, or whenever the condition is met to take an average. More often than not the variable would get 0, but occasionally it would get the number above.

Comment: It seems more related to something specific of your implementation. Can you post a little bit of context?

Comment: If it's a stack variable, it could just be whatever rubbish was previously on the stack, which itself might be "unreproducibly reproducible", depending on what your code does.

Comment: @Pedrom: Yes, I mentioned that in the question. The number, per se, is most likely confined to the context of my program. I'm wondering why it's always the same in different phases and iterations of my program, which made it especially hard to track down. The uninitialized variable was averaged without being initialized, i.e. was being added to and then divided by the number of adds. That's basically all the context there is. I can post some pseudocode but Im not entirely sure it adds anything to the question

Comment: I had seen that kind of behaviour before, depending of your OS sometimes the program will start in the same memory address that it was before. Specially if you are using .Net although I would expect to that to change if you reboot the PC.

Comment: Have you checked if the number is showing up for different values of readings.Count?

Comment: @Pedrom: Yes, it is. I control Count by upping or lowering the sampling/refresh rate. It seems inconsequential.

Comment: In any case, the problem is solved, I was just wondering why it was happening and if anyone had a rational explanation. I thought it was a good question but I guess not /shrug

Comment: It is intriguing but it is also very hard to find out what happened without further info. How did you solve it?

Comment: I just noticed the variable wasn't initialized after I caught a tick with a faulty average, which wasn't reproducible at all. More times than not the uninitialized variable would get 0, so the code worked.

Comment: I had an experience where an uninitialized variable had one value most of the time and sporadically another.  The variation was traced to the stack changes due to a timer interrupt.  Since you have variant behavior over time, this _may_ apply here.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look into that. I'll try to post the entire function of code in question to see if I can get a real explanation. Otherwise, I'm not sure why people are voting this closed, as it's very applicable to both debugging strategies and understanding language behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In the common floating-point encodings, 2.7916085e+035 is 0x7a570ec5 as a float and 0x474ae1d8a58be975 as a double, modulo endianness. These do not look like a typical text character string, a simple integer, or a common address. (The low bits of the double encoding are uncertain, as you did not capture enough decimal digits to determine them, but the high bits do not look meaningful.)

I expect there is little information to be deduced from this value by itself.

Comment: Yeah, I expressed doubt to that in the question. I still don't understand where it was coming from (which was very occasionally) and why it was always the same value, if it's supposedly garbage. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Good attempt to see if there was some magic to the number in an alternate view (integer).

Answer (score 1):

That double in 64-bit binary translates to

```
0100011101001010111000011101100010100101100010111110100000000000
```

or

```
01111010010101110000111011000101
```

as a 32-bit float.  Nearly all modern processors keep instructions and data separate--especially R/W data.  The exception, of course, is the old x86, which is a CISC processor, based on the 4004 from the days when every byte was at a premium, and even minicomputers did not have caches to work with.  With modern OS's, however, it is much more likely that, while 4 or 8KB pages were being moved around, a page of instructions was changed without zeroing out the old page.

The double version might be the equivalent to

```
Increment by 1, where r7 (EDI - extended destination index) is selected
```

The second, viewed as a float, looks like it would translate to either x86 or x86-64:

[How do I interpet this x86_64 assembly opcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180731/how-do-i-interpet-this-x86-64-assembly-opcode)

Answer (score 0):

The value that you see for an uninitialized variable is whatever happens to be in that memory location. It's not random; it's a value that was stored in memory by a previous function call.  For example:

```
void f() {
    int i = 3;
}

void g() {
    int i;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f();
    g();
    return 0;
}
```

Chances are, this program (assuming the compiler doesn't optimize out the initialization in `f()`) will write `3` to the console.

Comment: Then why was it 0 most of the time? Can it be attributed to the garbage collector? Dumb luck?

Comment: @glace - because whatever happened to be in that memory location got set to 0 most of the time. So in that sense it's dumb luck. C++ doesn't have built in garbage collection, so unless you're using an add-on garbage collector, that's not it.

Comment: Well, it is random in the sense reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. :)

Comment: It's Visual C++ .NET 4.0. I know the float type by itself is a primitive and isn't managed, by the list that I'm averaging is managed.

Comment: @GManNickG - undefined behavior does not mean random. It means that the language definition doesn't tell you what it does. That doesn't mean it's impossible to analyze, and in fact, what you get for the value is whatever is in memory. That is determined by what was done before the access, and that's what this question is about.

Comment: @PeteBecker: You're reading into my comment too much. :) I know what UB is. I just meant to say the words "undefined behavior" should probably appear somewhere, at the least to say why we get to perform this analysis.

Answer (score -1):

Floats are a base 2 number system. Because of this there are specific values that can not be accurately saved, and evaluate to an approximation.

Your output is probably giving you a value that specifically gets the same estimation. Try running through some common values that you get from the serial connection and see if you can find the value that is causing you grief. I personally would use a double for something like this instead of floats, especially if you are going to be doing any kind of calculations against those numbers.

Comment: The issue wasn't coming from the output. The uninitialized variable sporadically gets the same large value.

Comment: Miss-understood the question, my apologies. To me it looks similar to issues I have seen simply using Floats vs Doubles. There is a possibility that that is the max float size if that has any significance.

Comment: I thought it may have been the max float size too, but it isn't.

Comment: Strange. Are you re-initializing those variables at any time while the program is running?

Comment: Also I believe readings.count evaluates to an integer. Wonder if that could cause issues when dividing (or getting the remainder) a float by an integer.

Comment: Yeah. See my edit above, they're redeclared everytime the timer ticks if a certain condition is met. That condition can only be met one time per average, though.