# What is in the address of main?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

A simple piece of code like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

check the value in "&main" with gdb，I got 0xe5894855, I wonder what's this?

```
(gdb) x/x &main
0x401550 <main>:        0xe5894855
(gdb)
```

Comment: It's like asking why your phone number is 5894855... why not? In what context? What system?

Comment: Also... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: It's the address of the `main` function itself. See [function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840504/14637).

Comment: It is not the address, it is the "content" (instructions). The address is on the left side.

Answer (score 4):

```
(gdb) x/x &main
0x401550 <main>:        0xe5894855
(gdb)
```

`0xe5894855` is hex opcodes of the first instructions in main, but since you used `x/x` now `gdb` is displaying it as just a hex number and is backwards due to x86-64 being little-endian. `55` is the opcode for `push rbp` and the first instruction of `main`. Use `x/i &main` to view the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

> check the value in "&main" with gdb，I got 0xe5894855, I wonder what's this?

The C expression `&main` evaluates to a pointer to (function) `main`.

The gdb command

> ```
> x/x &main
> ```

prints (eXamines) the value stored at the address expressed by `&main`, in hexadecimal format (`/x`).  The result in your case is `0xe5894855`, but the C language does not specify the significance of that value.  In fact, C does not define any strictly conforming way even to read it from inside the program.

*In practice*, that value probably represents the first four bytes of the function's machine code, interpreted as a four-byte unsigned integer in native byte order. But that depends on implementation details both of GDB of the C implementation involved.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the `0x401550` is the address of main() and the hex goo to the right is the "contents" of that address, which doesn't make much sense since it's code stored there, not data.

To explain what that hex goo is coming from, we can toy around with some artificial examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf("%llx\n", (unsigned long long)&main);
}
```

Running this code on gcc x86_64, I get `401040` which is the address of main() on my particular system (this time). Then upon modifying the example into some ugly hard coding:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf("%llx\n", (unsigned long long)&main);
  printf("%.8x\n", *(unsigned int*)0x401040);
}
```

(Please note that accessing absolute addresses of program code memory like this is dirty hacking. It is very questionable practice and some systems might toss out an hardware exception if you attempt it.)

I get

```
401040
08ec8348
```

The gibberish second line is something similar to what gdb would give: the raw op codes for the instructions stored there.

(That is, it's actually a program that prints out the machine code used for printing out the machine code... and now my head hurts...)

Upon disassembly and generating a binary of the executable, then viewing numerical op codes with annotated assembly, I get:

```
        main:
         48 83 ec 08
401040   sub    rsp,0x8
```

Where the `48 83 ec 08` is the raw machine code, including the instruction `sub` with its parameters (x86 assembler isn't exactly my forte, but I believe 48 is ["REX prefix"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180731/how-do-i-interpet-this-x86-64-assembly-opcode) and 83 is the op code for `sub`). Upon attempting to print this as if it was integer data rather than machine code, it got tossed around according to x86 little endian ordering from `48 83 ec 08` to `08 ec 83 48`. And that's the hex gibberish `08ec8348` from before.